# Isssue with KMS permissions for EC2 insatnce profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Help please to find out the bug on my code, cause right now when Im running it, it works well except part creation of EC2 instances on ASG.
They terminated with error that not enough permissions on KMS key to encrypt/decrypt root device.

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "this" {
  name        = local.name
  description = var.lt_description
  image_id      = var.image_id
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  key_name      = var.key_name
  iam_instance_profile {
    arn = aws_iam_instance_profile.this.arn
  }

  network_interfaces {
    associate_public_ip_address = var.associate_public_ip_address
    security_groups = var.security_groups
  }

  block_device_mappings {
    device_name = var.device_name
    ebs {
      volume_size = var.device_volume_size
      volume_type = var.device_volume_type
      delete_on_termination = var.device_delete_on_termiation
      encrypted = var.device_enable_encryption
      kms_key_id = var.device_enable_encryption ? var.device_encryption_key : null
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "this" {
  availability_zones = var.availability_zones
  desired_capacity   = var.asg_desired_capacity
  max_size           = var.asg_max_size
  min_size           = var.asg_min_size

  launch_template {
    id      = aws_launch_template.this.id
    version = "$Latest"
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "instance_policy" {

  statement {
    actions   = [
      "ec2:*"
    ]
    resources = ["*"]
  }

  statement {
    actions = [
       "kms:Encrypt",
       "kms:Decrypt",
       "kms:ReEncrypt",
       "kms:GenerateDataKey",
       "kms:DescribeKey",
       "kms:GenerateDataKeyWithoutPlainText"
    ]
    resources = [var.device_encryption_key]
  }
}

resource aws_iam_role "this" {
   path                = "/terraform/instances/"
   name                = "${local.name}-asg-iam-role"
   description         = var.role_description
   assume_role_policy  = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_policy.json
}

resource aws_iam_policy "instance_policy" {
  path                = "/terraform/instances/"
  name                = "${local.name}-instance-policy"
  description         = "${local.name} IAM KMS policy"
  policy              = data.aws_iam_policy_document.instance_policy.json
}

resource aws_iam_role_policy_attachment "this" {
  role                = aws_iam_role.this.name
  policy_arn          = aws_iam_policy.instance_policy.arn
}

resource aws_iam_instance_profile "this" {
  path                = "/terraform/instances/"
  name                = "${local.name}-instances-profile"
  role                = aws_iam_role.this.name
}
```

Can confirm that all elements created without any problems and terraform return green light. Only issue with permissions and ASG which terminates instances due to luck of permissions

Error termination :

> Client.InternalError: Client error on launch

Can also confirm that without encryption its working

Answer (score 1):

you need to give ASG service-linked role access to your KMS key. more information [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/autoscaling-service-linked-role.html)